# Save webpage displayed in webbrowser control

Tags: windows, webbrowser-control

It is possible to save the content displayed on a `webbrowser` control in a Windows application, giving that there's no access to the source code? The webpage is downloaded in a proprietary format from a HTTP server, so sniffing the HTTP traffic doesn't help too much (it's a base64-encoded data which decoded gives a binary file without any recogniseable headers).

I think a good solution will be to load the application in Wine, giving the open-source nature of it, and trying to extract the data somehow from the Gecko HTML viewer, but I don't have any idea how to start...

Any better solutions than recompiling Wine to display the content of displaying webpages? I hope for some magic tool to display HTML source from a `webbrowser` control, but any starting point will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I successfully did this with [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/), with just three lines of code. Just attach to the IE Control and call `IEPropertyGet` on it. Sample code:

```
#include <IE.au3> 
$oIE = _IEAttach("window_title", "embedded");
ConsoleWrite(_IEPropertyGet($oIE, "outerhtml"));
```

Now in AutoIt's console will appear the source code of the displayed page in embedded `webbrowser` control.